# How do I replicate the directory structure to a remote Linux server?

Tags: linux, rsync, scp, administration

I want to replicate a complex directory structure from one Linux server to another remote server start at a certain sub-directory.

I don't want the contents of the files, I just want to preserve the structure, owner and permissions as the server to be cloned contains a large volume of data that must not be copied to the new machine.

I'm guessing that this could be done somehow by tar-ing up the folder structure and un-taring it on the remote machine. Or by using rsync to copy without sending the data. Or possibly by using find to create a shell script.

If anyone has the one-liner at hand that accomplishes this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `find` and `cpio` to make a list of subdirectories from the current working directory thus:

```
find . -type d -print | cpio -oO dirs.cpio
```

To rebuild that directory hierarchy on the remote machine, copy over the `dirs.cpio` file to the desired location and run:

```
cpio -iI dirs.cpio
```

Comment: Both answers were great but I'm giving the best answer to this for teaching me about cpio.

Answer (score 1):

one solution might be

`find . -type d > dirs`

to find the directories, then use that file with the `-T` option of `tar`:

`tar cpzT dirs -f dest_file.tar.gz`

which should create a compressed archive (`z`) preserving permissions (`p`) by archiving only the files listed (`T dirs`). Transfer file, uncompress with

`tar xpzf dest_file.tar.gz`

and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to recursively copy only directories under a source path to a destination directory:

```
rsync --archive --verbose --filter="+ */" --filter="- *" /path/to/src/ /path/to/dest/
rsync --archive --verbose --filter="+ */" --filter="- *" /path/to/apache/logs/ user@domain:/path/to/apache/logs/
```

Using options `--include` and `--exclude` instead of `--filter` rules with an older version of `rsync`:

```
rsync --archive --verbose --include="*/" --exclude="- *" /path/to/src/ /path/to/dest/
rsync --archive --verbose --include="*/" --exclude="*" /path/to/apache/logs/ user@domain:/path/to/apache/logs/
```